# UFW status is getting problem running iptables

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I want to use UFW (version 0.36) but I get this error when running `ufw status`:

```
ERROR: problem running iptables: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Perhaps you want to use the -w option?
```

Same error when running `iptables -L` without the `-w` argument, but how to fix the `ufw`? I also run on the server `kubernetes` with `flannel` and `docker`.